# setlocale() doesn't read from bindtextdomain() dir C++

Tags: c++, gettext, setlocale

I'm testing `gettext()` to change the language of a simple "hello, world!" string.
I generated the .pot and changed, .po and .mo for 2 languages `ja_JP` and `pt_PT`.
For `pt_PT` it worked well but `ja_JP` when I change the env var `LANG` and call `setlocale()` it tries to read a diff file from it was supposed.
The point is to change the language without messing with the `locale` command, in this case `locale -a` doesn't have `ja_JP`. Programs like inkscape allow the user to change the language without doing it.

Test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <libintl.h>

std::string mygetenv(const char* var) {
    std::string rv;
    char * ptr = std::getenv(var);
    if(ptr) rv = ptr;
    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string pwd = mygetenv("PWD");
    char* l = getenv("LANG");
    std::cout << "getenv(LANG): " << (l ? l : "NULL") << std::endl;
    char* s = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << "setlocale(): " << (s ? s : "NULL") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "textdomain(): " << textdomain("gt") << "\n" << std::endl;
    pwd.append("/locales");
    std::cout << "bindtextdomain(): " << bindtextdomain("gt", pwd.c_str()) << std::endl;
    
    bind_textdomain_codeset("gt", "UTF-8");
    
    std::cout << "Default: " << gettext("hello, world!") << std::endl;
    setenv("LANG", "ja_JP.UTF-8", 1);
    s = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << "setlocale(): " << (s ? s : "NULL") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ja_JP: " << gettext("hello, world!") << std::endl;
    setenv("LANG", "pt_PT.UTF-8", 1);
    s = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << "setlocale(): " << (s ? s : "NULL") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pt_PT: " << gettext("hello, world!") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
getenv(LANG): en_US.UTF-8
setlocale(): LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_TIME=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_NAME=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_PT.UTF-8
bindtextdomain(): /home/<USER>/projects/gettext_test/locales
textdomain(): gt

Default: hello, world!
setlocale(): NULL
ja_JP: hello, world!
setlocale(): pt_PT.UTF-8
pt_PT: ola, mundo!
```

And to check for which files it's looking for I used `strace`.

pt_PT:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/<USER>/projects/gettext_test/locales/pt_PT.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/gt.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/<USER>/projects/gettext_test/locales/pt_PT.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/gt.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/<USER>/projects/gettext_test/locales/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/gt.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
pt_PT: ola, mundo!
```

ja_JP:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/ja_JP.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/ja_JP.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/ja_JP/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/ja.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/ja.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/ja_JP.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/ja_JP.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/ja_JP/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/ja.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/ja.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/ja/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
ja_JP: hello, world!
```

For some reason it doesn't try the `locale` folder in the project dir.

Dir structure with link to files:

```
    <project>/
        |- locales/
            |- [gt.pot][1]
            |- ja_JP/
                |- [ja.pot][2]
                |- [ja.po][3]
                |- LC_MESSAGES/
                    |- [gt.mo][4]
            |- pt_PT/
                |- [pt.pot][5]
                |- [pt.po][6]
                |- LC_MESSAGES/
                    |- [gt.mo][7]
```

1. http://ix.io/2Hj6
2. http://ix.io/2Hjc
3. http://ix.io/2Hj7
4. http://ix.io/2Hjd
5. http://ix.io/2Hjg
6. http://ix.io/2Hje
7. http://ix.io/2Hjh

I can't uderstand why `pt_PT` works but `ja_JP` doesn't

EDIT: adding makefile I used

```
all:
    g++ -o gt main.cpp

gen-template:
    xgettext -d gt -o gt.pot main.cpp -p ./locales

gen-po:
    sed --in-place ./locales/pt_PT/pt.pot --expression='s/CHARSET/UTF-8/'
    msginit -l pt_PT -o ./locales/pt_PT/pt.po -i ./locales/pt_PT/pt.pot
    sed --in-place ./locales/ja_JP/ja.pot --expression='s/CHARSET/UTF-8/'
    msginit -l ja_JP -o ./locales/ja_JP/ja.po -i ./locales/ja_JP/ja.pot

gen-mo:
    msgfmt ./locales/pt_PT/pt.po -o ./locales/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/gt.mo 
    msgfmt ./locales/ja_JP/ja.po -o ./locales/ja_JP/LC_MESSAGES/gt.mo 

update-pot:
    msgmerge ./locales/pt_PT/pt.po ./locales/pt_PT/pt.pot -o ./locales/pt_PT/pt.po
    msgmerge ./locales/ja_JP/ja.po ./locales/ja_JP/ja.pot -o ./locales/ja_JP/ja.po
```

EDIT: It works on Windows! but can't put it to work on Linux (using Ubuntu rn)

EDIT: added output `locale -a`:

```
$ locale -a

C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
pt_PT.utf8
.utf8
```

Comment: Read the doc for `getenv`. If it fails, it returns a `NULL`. A `std::string` doesn't like reading from `NULL` and `std::string::c_str()` will never return `NULL` (which is what you test for) - so, if you read an environment variable that doesn't exist, your program has undefined behavior. Instead do: `std::string pwd; auto pwdptr = getenv("PWD"); if(pwdptr) pwd = pwdptr;` and the same for all the others.

Comment: You could also add a helper function to make it easier. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/9exvKj)

Comment: Thx, but this is just a test code so I would prefer to maintain in as it is and try to solve the issue first since the base code was in C and I wanted a string to test other stuff

Comment: A potential UB should be prio 1. Why not start by making the code safe?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the code has been updated and all the output

Comment: That's good, although, you kept the potential UB:s. Why? Also, noone will be able to compile the code in your question without adding to it. Make it into a [mcve] so that people can copy it and compile it _as-is_.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the pwd string is no longer being compared if NULL in the updated code. I just do an append and pass it to bindtextdomain, which we can see the return value of it.

Comment: Read the first 3 sentenses in my first comment. This: `std::string pwd = getenv("PWD");` is a potential UB. If `getenv` returns `NULL`, your program may crash, or worse, _not_ crash, but do something completely wild, like setting your computer on fire.

Comment: @TedLyngmo mb, in that case I added the complete code

Comment: That looks better. What does `mb` mean? Are the `.pot` files crucial to be able to show the problem? I get 3 different locales set when running your code, but then again, I don't have any `.pot`, `.po` or `.mo` files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `ja_JP` to work, when the locale `ja_JP` is not installed. When you look at the gettext source code you will see that it does a call `setlocale("ja_JP", NULL)` to determine the currently set locale. In your case, this call returns `NULL` and therefore no catalog (`.mo` file) at all is loaded.

The intl library does *not* check any environment variable. The `setlocale()` function checks the environment, when you call it with an empty string as the second argument. That is then called the "native" environment. But since you don't have `ja_JP` installed, switching the locale fails, and therefore subsequent calls to `gettext()` do not "know" the language you were trying to select.

The rationale behind that is that your code and all linked libraries use the same language and(!) encoding. It should be prevented that for example the libc messages are in `pt_PT` using iso-8859-1 and your program code outputs messages in `ja_JP` and UTF-8.

You can actually simplify your test code and instead of setting environment variables you can just hardcode the locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "ja_JP.UTF-8")`. It has the same effect and makes it even clearer that your code cannot work as expected when the Japanese locale is not installed.

The strace output for `ja_JP` is most likely not caused by your code but by some library function. Compare the flags in the second argument to `openat()`. For `pt_PT` they are `O_RDONLY` but for `ja_JP` they are `O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC`. So the calls to `openat()` origin from different locations.

Comment: I will try that out, but the point of this code is to work without generating the locales, like inkscape does.

Comment: Same issue when setting "ja_JP.UTF-8" on `setlocale()` directly, if I comment the setlocale call when trying to change to japanese those openat calls disappear.

Comment: If you want to do it the same way as inkscape does, you have to inspect their source code. But the standard gettext works like I described it. You *have* to install all locales that you want to use.